# Docker container with Selenium and Chrome webdriver crashes when multiple containers run in parallel on AWS Batch

Tags: python, docker, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb, aws-batch

We are running AWS Batch jobs that launch Docker containers to run Selenium and Chrome with python 3.6.  When we set it up to run multiple containers per server, jobs often start up, run for a couple minutes, then crash with `chrome not reachable`:

```
  File "/home/seluser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 597, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/home/seluser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/seluser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/seluser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
```

When we changed the Batch configuration to ensure there is only one container per server, all jobs went through successfully.

**It seems like multiple jobs running on the same server are interfering with each other. They should be isolated in their own Docker containers, so what could be happening? How can we find out what's going wrong and prevent it?**

Configuration to allow multiple containers per server, so that we can run more jobs on fewer servers. Many jobs run with this configuration crash when trying to access Chrome.

Batch Job definition - multiple containers per server:

- vCPUs 1
- Memory 3072 MiB

Batch Compute environment - multiple containers per server:

- Minimum vCPUs 0
- Desired vCPUs 0
- Maximum vCPUs 20
- Instance types optimal
- Allocation strategy BEST_FIT

Configuration to allow a single containers per server. All jobs succeed but we need more servers.

Batch Job definition - single container per server:

- vCPUs 2
- Memory 7168 MiB

Compute environment - single container per server:

- Minimum vCPUs 0
- Desired vCPUs 0
- Maximum vCPUs 20
- Instance types m4.large
- Allocation strategy BEST_FIT

This forces one container per server because m4.large has 2 vCPU, and the job definition specifies 2 vCPUs.

AWS Batch environment: ECS Docker: version 18.09.9-ce, build 039a7df

These are the flags ECS is running our containers with:

```
root       4824      1  8 19:04 ?        00:00:39 /usr/bin/dockerd \
  --default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --storage-driver devicemapper \
  --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/docker-docker--pool \
  --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_removal=true --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=true \
  --storage-opt dm.fs=ext4 --storage-opt dm.use_deferred_deletion=true
```

Here is how we set up Selenium / Chrome:

```
import pyvirtualdisplay
from selenium import webdriver

pyvirtualdisplay.Display(visible=False, size=(1900, 1200))

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {}
prefs["download.default_directory"] = self.download_dir
prefs["plugins.always_open_pdf_externally"] = True
prefs["profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads"] = 1
prefs["plugins.plugins_list"] = [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}]
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
   chrome_options=self._options(),
   service_log_path=os.path.join(config.WORKING_DIRECTORY, "driver.log"))
```

Other switches we've tried but are not using now:

- `--headless` - using pyvirtualdisplay instead to work around timeouts related to waiting for files to appear in download_dir with headless chrome
- `--disable-gpu` - doesn't apply since we're running on Linux
- `--disable-setuid-sandbox` - overlaps with `--no-sandbox`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that AWS Batch creates docker containers with `host` networking, which resulting in port conflicts when we tried to run multiple instances of Xvfb.

More details:

http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless sounds like what we were seeing:

> If you're running tests headlessly across different builds at the same
>   time (e.g., in parallel) on your CI server, then jobs will start to
>   break unexpectedly. This is because of a display port collision with
>   Xvfb (e.g., two or more Xvfb sessions trying to run on the same
>   display port at the same time).

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=254487

> AWS Batch communicates with Compute Resources via the ECS Agent which
>   is instructed to start jobs with NetworkMode set to "host" as you have
>   already determined. Currently the service is not designed to run Jobs
>   that are listening for external network requests into the container
>   instance.

https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

> If you use the host network mode for a container, that container’s
>   network stack is not isolated from the Docker host (the container
>   shares the host’s networking namespace), and the container does not
>   get its own IP-address allocated. For instance, if you run a container
>   which binds to port 80 and you use host networking, the container’s
>   application is available on port 80 on the host’s IP address.

from `man Xserver`:

> :displaynumber
>              The  X server runs as the given displaynumber, which by default
>              is 0.  If multiple X servers are to  run  simultaneously  on  a
>              host,  each must have a unique display number.

We were using PyVirtualDisplay to wrap Xvfb. But PyVirtualDisplay does not add a display param (ie :123) when launching Xvfb. I tried adding `check_startup=True`, but that failed with `XStartTimeoutError('No display number returned by X server',)`

We switched to using [xvfbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper) to create the virtual display. xvfbwrapper "randomly chooses a display number and tries to acquire a lock for this number". The Xvfb command line looks like Xvfb :35877838 -screen 0 1900x1200x24

With this configuration, we successfully ran jobs with multiple containers per server.