# How do you run multiple AWS Batch jobs with MultiProcessing, mp.Manager(), without conflicting port addresses error Address already in use?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, aws-batch

How do you fix AWS Batch conflicting port allocation when using multiprocessing? I am running multiple batch containers using multiprocessing. When two batch jobs run they fail with Address already in use. This SO question has the same problem [Docker container with Selenium and Chrome webdriver crashes when multiple containers run in parallel on AWS Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791670/docker-container-with-selenium-and-chrome-webdriver-crashes-when-multiple-contai/59845831#59845831).

This is the problem

> AWS Batch communicates with Compute Resources via the ECS Agent which
> is instructed to start jobs with NetworkMode set to "host" as you have
> already determined. Currently the service is not designed to run Jobs
> that are listening for external network requests into the container
> instance.

Code:

```py
    import multiprocessing as mp
    ...
    proc = []
    mgr = mp.Manager()
    mgr_queue = mgr.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=func, args=(x, y, mgr_queue))
    p.start()
    ...
```

Error:

> Process SyncManager-1: Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
> self.run()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 583, in _run_server
> server = cls._Server(registry, address, authkey, serializer)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 156, in **init**
> self.listener = Listener(address=address, backlog=16)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 453, in **init**
> self._listener = SocketListener(address, family, backlog)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 596, in **init**
> self._socket.bind(address) OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Based on the [documentation for Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) which is SyncManager with a BaseManager

```
class multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager([address[, authkey]])
Create a BaseManager object.

Once created one should call start() or get_server().serve_forever() to ensure that the manager object refers to a started manager process.

address is the address on which the manager process listens for new connections. If address is None then an arbitrary one is chosen.
```

Since I do not provide a port to mp.Manager() it appears as though it would be an arbitrary port but that is not true, how do you fix this? I would happily change the networking "host" if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the bug is due to the implementation of Unix abstract addresses in Python 3.9 ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18866)). This caused the default socket address for the `multiprocessing.Manager()` on Unix machines to be not very random. As noted by the OP, containers share their addresses with the host when running on AWS Batch, so this non-randomness makes it very likely (or even guaranteed) for the socket addresses to conflict across containers on the same machine. The [suggested fix](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/97514) is to set `multiprocessing.util.abstract_sockets_supported = False` before initializing your `Manager`. This makes the socket addresses extremely random again, ensuring they won't conflict.

So just add:

```
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.util
...
multiprocessing.util.abstract_sockets_supported = False
mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
...
```